# Angular 11 - google-maps Switch Map Style

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm happy to see that there is an [angular npm module for google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/google-maps)

I'm using the last version of @angular/google-maps (11) and the last version of angular (11)

I have found how to style the map and how to implement it, but I don't see any documentation about how to switch the style from darkmode to lightmode.

Maybe you can help ?

I tried to make a function of the options, but somehow it freezes the browser doing so

HTML

```
...
[options]="getOptions()"
...
```

Component

```
getOption(){
  let options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
  mapTypeId:"roadmap",
  panControl: false,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  zoomControl: false,
  scrollwheel: false,
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  styles:(this.isLight) ? styleLight:styleDark,
 }

 return options;
}
```

To reproduce the code -BUILD

```
 ng new google-map
 cd google-map
 npm install @angular/google-map
```

create the style in app folder

```
export const light: google.maps.MapTypeStyle[] = [
    {
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#f5f5f5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#616161"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#f5f5f5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#bdbdbd"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#f0f0f0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#fafafa"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#eeeeee"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#757575"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.business",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#ffffff"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#e5e5e5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#cfcfcf"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#9e9e9e"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#ffffff"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#ffffff"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#6e6e6e"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#757575"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#dadada"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#fcfcfc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#808080"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#616161"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#cfcfcf"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#fafafa"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#a6a6a6"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#9e9e9e"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.line",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#e5e5e5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.station",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#eeeeee"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#c9c9c9"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#ffffff"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#050505"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#9e9e9e"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

create the second style light

```
   export const dark: google.maps.MapTypeStyle[] = [
    {
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#212121"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#757575"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#212121"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#757575"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative.country",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#9e9e9e"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative.locality",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#bdbdbd"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#303030"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#181818"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#212121"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#303030"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#212121"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#757575"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.attraction",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#303030"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.business",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#181818"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#181818"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#303030"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#616161"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#1b1b1b"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#2c2c2c"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#8a8a8a"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#373737"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#1b1b1b"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#5f5f5f"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#3c3c3c"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#000000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#5f5f5f"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#4e4e4e"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#000000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#000000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#616161"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#757575"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#000000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#3d3d3d"
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

and finally the component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {light} from './light';
import {dark} from './dark';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<google-map
  width="100%"
  [options]="options"
  >`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'google-map';
  isLight = false;
  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    styles:(this.isLight) ? dark:light,
}

}
```

Do not forget to add the google api in the index.html

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

In order to make it works, I guess you need an API Key.

My problem is how with a external button to the map, can I switch between dark mode and light mode.

THanks

Comment: A [mcve]. Did you click on that link and read about what it is? We don't even know what module you are using. You provide half of a JSON object, half of your code, a bit of HTML that isn't HTML... up to you really.

Comment: I found this explaination but I don't know how to implement in my code :( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/style-selector

Comment: However, if I do someting like this.zoom++ the map is properly zooming in, but I'm still looking to change the style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using

```
@ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: false }) map: GoogleMap
```

And

```
ngOnChanges() {
  this.change(this.isLight);
}

change(input) {
  if(this.map != undefined){
    let styles = (input) ? styleDark : styleLight;
    this.map.googleMap.setOptions({styles:styles});
  }
}
```